# Flutter Reusable Form Widget

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart

I have implemented class with a method addTicket(),When I reuse this class I want to have change "db.collection" name and "Navigator" according to relevant page in my app.So how can I do it ?

```
class AddNewTicket extends StatefulWidget {  
  @override
  _AddNewTicketState createState() => _AddNewTicketState();
}


class _AddNewTicketState extends State<AddNewTicket> {

  addTicket() async {
    if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
      _formKey.currentState.save();
      try{
        DocumentReference ref = await db.collection('CostalLineTicketDetails').
        document(ticketCato).collection("Tickets").add();
        setState(() => id = ref.documentID);
        Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => CostalLine()));
      }catch(e){
        print(e);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
  addTicket(String collectionName, Widget widgetPage) async {
    if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
      _formKey.currentState.save();
      try{
        DocumentReference ref = await db.collection(collectionName).
        document(ticketCato).collection("Tickets").add();
        setState(() => id = ref.documentID);
        Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => widgetPage));
      }catch(e){
        print(e);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: how can I get those inputs collectionName and widgetPage using AddNewTicket stateful widget?

Comment: why not just create a file that will contain methods that you can call?

Comment: in your code you can do `final ticket = AddNewTicket();
    ticket.createState().addTicket("collection", myHomePage());`

Comment: How can I  call AddNewTicket("collection" , myHomePage())  like this

Comment: what do you mean? You need to create a new AddNewTicket object, then create the state and then call `addTicket("collection", myHomePage());` and just pass a String that will be your collection and a Widget